# Copying the most recent file in a folder

Tags: applescript

How can I locate and copy (to clipboard) the most recent file in a folder?

Here's the path to the folder:

`/Users/myuser/Desktop/Screenshots`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to sort (get files of folder "Screenshots" of desktop) by creation date
set the clipboard to last item of theFiles as alias
```

To copy the image to the clipboard in pure AppleScript is cumbersome. It's pretty easy with a few lines AppleScriptObjC:

```
use framework "Foundation"

tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to sort (get files of folder "Screenshots" of desktop) by creation date
set imageFile to last item of theFiles as text
set theData to current application's NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile:(POSIX path of imageFile)
set pasteBoard to current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
pasteBoard's clearContents()
pasteBoard's setData:theData forType:(current application's NSPasteboardTypeTIFF)
```

Comment: It seems to do something as my clipboard gets erased with nothing. But the image is not set as in the clipboard.

Comment: You wrote *copy (to clipboard) the most recent file* rather then the **contents** of the file. To copy the image you need a little help from AppleScriptObjC (Cocoa). I updated the answer.

Comment: BTW. Do you have any clue why it takes like 3-4 seconds for the script to run?

Comment: If there are many files in the folder the sorting takes some time. The Finder in AppleScript is not very quick. You could write the entire script in ApplScriptObjC, that's much faster.

Comment: You are correct. I only had 250 screenshots and it took 3-4 seconds. After wiping the folder it run in ~0.1s. You've been really helpful and I'm grateful for that! Have a nice day!